# How to stop parallel region of OpenMP 2.0

Tags: c++, openmp

I look for a better way to cancel my threads. 
In my approach, I use a shared variable and if this variable is set, I just throw a continue. This finishes my threads fast, but threads keep theoretically spawning and ending, which seems not elegant. 
So, is there a better way to solve the issue (`break` is not supported by my OpenMP)?

I have to work with Visual, so my OpenMP Lib is outdated and there is no way around that. Consequently, I think `#omp cancel` will not work

```
int progress_state = RunExport;
#pragma omp parallel
{
#pragma omp for
  for (int k = 0; k < foo.z; k++)
  for (int j = 0; j < foo.y; j++)
  for (int i = 0; i < foo.x; i++) {
    if (progress_state == StopExport) {
      continue;
    }

// do some fancy shit 

// yeah here is a condition for speed due to the critical
#pragma omp critical
    if (condition) {
      progress_state = StopExport;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you be clearer about what specifically is "bullshit" here?  And why you consider it "bullshit"?  If we don't know why your solution is *bad*, we cannot suggest one that is *better*, because we don't know *what criteria* you are using.  If you just want our opinion, then this is off-topic for SO.

Comment: How about `break`?

Comment: @dgrat So edit that into the question.  Possibly replace "bullshit" with "when I set StopExport, threads continue to launch and they all waste a bunch of CPU" or whatever specific problem you are looking to solve.

Comment: @dgrat In that case you are just asking for how to best break out of nested `for` loops. Also, OMP is most certainly not spawning new threads. In fact, the default is most likely a fixed split (since you specified no `dynamic` or `guided` schedule) between the threads, which is suboptimal if the workload is as uneven as "may be cancelled for this thread" implies. On that matter: Please add your OMP version to the question.

Comment: And in general, the code you posted makes very little sense. `progress_state` is a per-thread variable. You set it in a critical section (that's pointless) and consequently you are currently only cancelling the loop iterations of _that thread_. The other threads will keep running. So which `k` get processed after `condition` is reached depends on how the loop is split up between the threads. Did you maybe mean to not make `progress_state` thread-local?

Comment: @MaxLanghof I think this was a flaw. Had to remove some code for the example ..

Comment: @dgrat Please invest the effort to provide proper example code, even (or rather especially) if it is not your real code. As it stands your `progress_state` is still subject to data races (written in the critical section and possibly read in parallel in the `if`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it the simple way of "just `continue` in all remaining iterations if cancellation is requested". That can just be the first check in the outermost loop (and given that you have several nested loops, that will probably not have any measurable overhead).

```
std::atomic<int> progress_state = RunExport;

// You could just write #pragma omp parallel for instead of these two nested blocks.
#pragma omp parallel
{
#pragma omp for
  for (int k = 0; k < foo.z; k++)
  {
    if (progress_state == StopExport)
      continue;

    for (int j = 0; j < foo.y; j++)
    {
      // You can add break statements in these inner loops.
      // OMP only parallelizes the outermost loop (at least given the way you wrote this)
      // so it won't care here.
      for (int i = 0; i < foo.x; i++)
      {

        // ...

        if (condition) {
          progress_state = StopExport;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Generally speaking, OMP will not suddenly spawn new threads or end existing ones, especially not within one parallel region. This means there is little overhead associated with running a few more tiny iterations. This is even more true given that the default scheduling in your case is most likely `static`, meaning that each thread knows its start and end index right away. Other scheduling modes would have to call into the OMP runtime every iteration (or every few iterations) to request more work, but that won't happen here. The compiler will basically see this code for the threaded work:

```
// Not real omp functions.
int myStart = __omp_static_for_my_start();
int myEnd = __omp_static_for_my_end();
for (int k = myStart; k < myEnd; ++k)
{
  if (progress_state == StopExport)
    continue;

  // etc.
}
```

You might try a non-atomic thread-local "should I cancel?" flag that starts as `false` and can only be changed to `true` (which the compiler may understand and fold into the loop condition). But I doubt you will see significant overhead either way, at least on x86 where `int` is atomic anyway.

> which seems not elegant

OMP 2.0 does not exactly shine with respect to elegance. I mean, iterating over a `std::vector` requires at least one `static_cast` to silence signed -> unsigned conversion warnings. So unless you have specific evidence of this pattern causing a performance problem, there is little reason not to use it.